# Is it possible to achieve this without defining a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a Python program which would take a string and print the longest substring in it which is also in alphabetical order. For example:

the_string = "abcdefgghhisdghlqjwnmonty"
The longest substring in alphabetical order here would be "abcdefgghhis"

I'm not allowed to define my own functions and can't use lists. So here's what I came up with:

```
def in_alphabetical_order(string):
    for letter in range(len(string) - 1):
        if string[letter] > string[letter + 1]:
            return False
    return True    

s = "somestring"
count = 0

for char in range(len(s)):
    i = 0
    while i <= len(s):
        sub_string = s[char : i]
        if (len(sub_string) > count) and (in_alphabetical_order(sub_string)):
            count = len(sub_string)
            longest_string = sub_string
        i += 1

print("Longest substring in alphabetical order is: " + longest_string)
```

This obviously contains a function that is not built-in. How can I check whether the elements of the substring candidate is in alphabetical order without defining this function?  In other words: How can I implement what this function does for me into the code (e.g. by using another for loop in the code somewhere or something)?

Comment: I am not sure what you want to do : do you want to remove the dedicated function?

Comment: i think it should be `for letter in range(len(string) ):` insted of  `len(string)-1`

Comment: @Paradox Yeah, I want to be able to check whether a string is in alphabetical order, without defining a function. Like with using another for loop in the code somewhere or something. I'm just a beginner so don't know my way around the language well yet.

Comment: @StavrosAvramidis `for letter in range(len(string) - 1) ` the minus is there to not overstep the index numbers.

Comment: @BiggusDickus  yes but range(a) counts until a-1

Comment: @StavrosAvramidis Should have been clearer: There is also `string[letter + 1]` in the line below. That would go beyond the index numbers available I think if I had wrote `len(string)` instead of `len(string) - 1`

Comment: @StavrosAvramidis I do not see why you would not want to define such a function. Or maybe you would like to know if there is a more "pythonic" way to do so, such as a built-in function? Your question does not seem to be clear enough.

Comment: @Paradox i think you confused nicknames

Comment: Yes, my bad. My comment was intended for @BiggusDickus

Comment: @Paradox It's just a limitation. I'm simply not allowed to define a function of my own. (sounds pointless, I know.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just going by your code you can move the operation of the function into the loop and use a variable to store what would have been the return value.

I would recommend listening to bill the lizard to help with the way you solve the problem

```
s = "somestring"
count = 0
longest_string = ''


for char in range(len(s)):
    i = 0
    while i <= len(s):
        sub_string = s[char : i]
        in_order = True

        for letter in range(len(sub_string) - 1):
            if sub_string[letter] > sub_string[letter + 1]:
                in_order = False
                break

        if (len(sub_string) > count) and (in_order):
            count = len(sub_string)
            longest_string = sub_string
        i += 1

print("Longest substring in alphabetical order is: " + longest_string)
```

Comment: This was exactly what I wanted to do! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to check the whole substring with a function call to see if it is alphabetical. You can just check one character at a time.

Start at the first character. If the next character is later in the alphabet, keep moving along in the string. When you reach a character that's earlier in the alphabet than the previous character, you've found the longest increasing substring starting at the first character. Save it and start over from the second character.

Each time you find the longest substring starting at character N, check to see if it is longer than the previous longest substring. If it is, replace the old one.

Comment: That sounds much more efficient. I'll try and implement that if I can, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution based off of what you had:

```
s = 'abcdefgghhisdghlqjwnmonty'

m, n = '', ''

for i in range(len(s) - 1):
    if s[i + 1] < s[i]:
        if len(n) > len(m):
            m = n
        n = s[i]
    else:
        n += s[i]
```

Output:

```
m

'abcdefgghhi'
```